# CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'INavigationBase' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently explore Entity Framework with Windows Form while following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/winforms) i came across this code
which gives compile time error:

```
private void dgvCategories_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.contextDB != null && this.dgvCategories.CurrentRow !=null)
            {
                var category = this.dgvCategories.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                if(category != null)
                {
                  //  this.contextDB.Entry(category).Collection(a => a.Products).Load();
                    this.contextDB.Entry(category).Collection(a => a.Products).Load();

                }
            }
        }
```

CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'INavigationBase' because it is not a delegate type.

The error is in a => a.Products.

Edit: Here is my DB context class

```
 internal class ContextDB : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCategory> categories { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> purchases { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<cate>
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=products.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>().HasData(
                new ProductCategory { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Cheese" },
                new ProductCategory { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Meat" },
                new ProductCategory { CategoryId = 3, Name = "Fish" },
                new ProductCategory { CategoryId = 4, Name = "Bread" }
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
  new Product { ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Cheddar", Price = 50 },
            new Product { ProductId = 10, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Parmesan" },
            new Product { ProductId = 12, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Beef" },
            new Product { ProductId = 13, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Chicken" },
            new Product { ProductId = 17, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Mutton" },
            new Product { ProductId = 21, CategoryId = 3, Name = "Salmon" },
            new Product { ProductId = 22, CategoryId = 3, Name = "Tuna" }
                );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the DbContext along with any configurations you've applied to the models?

Comment: yes updated the db context.  While i didn't apply any specific thing in config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed at least one important part of the tutorial, `DataBoundItem` returns an `object` and you need to cast it to `Category` to proceed:

```
var category = (Category)this.dgvCategories.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

So the compiler can pick up the generic version of the method - [`DbContext.Entry<TEntity>(TEntity)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-8.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-entry-1(-0)) which returns the generic [`EntityEntry<TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1?view=efcore-8.0) which allows passing lambdas to methods like `Collection`.